# Updating SQL with Python - Incorrect number of bindings

Tags: python, sqlite

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.execute("INSERT INTO file_routes (file_route) VALUES (?)", (file_route))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

I create the table with this

```
createTable_filenames = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        file_routes(
            routes_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            file_route TEXT
        )
"""
```

[image]

This is the code I am trying to run and it doesn't work

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('fantasyresults.db')
c = conn.cursor()

file_route = "test"

c.execute("INSERT INTO file_routes (file_route) VALUES (?)", (file_route))
conn.commit()
```

I don't understand why this code works, I set up the structure the same way.
`c.execute` than `("INSERT INTO <tablename> (<column id>) VALUES (?)", (<variable>))`

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO draftkings (account_id, sport, game_type, entry_key, entry_name, opponent, contest_key, contest_date, position, points, winnings, winnings_tickets, contest_entries, entry_fee, prize_pool, places_paid)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (account_id, sport, game_type, entry_key, entry_name, opponent, contest_key, contest_date, position, points, winnings, winnings_tickets, contest_entries, entry_fee, prize_pool, places_paid))
```

Any help is much appreciated, I don't know what I am not seeing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it is considering the parameter as `string` instead of `tuple` as that's the expected behavior in python for a tuple with single element.

Try updating the parameter tuple as

```
(file_route, )
```

have a **comma** after the parameter.

Comment: O M G I love you haha, wow I spent like 2 hours on SQLite documentation for python lol I laughed so hard when you just wrote the comma

Comment: You answered it so quick, have to wait before can mark as answer >.<